# how to fetch multiple rows with via same column in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, row, identity-column

I am trying to fetch multiple rows via same column. I used having clause, group by order by everything but still it is returning only one row.

```
   function slots($condition){
    $this->db->select('slot_id');
    $this->db->from('mn_date_slot');
    $this->db->where('journey_date',$condition);
    $this->db->group_by('journey_date');
    $this->db->order_by('slot_id','desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

> i want to fetch slot_id from 4 rows where journey_date is same.

Comment: Please post your table structure and some sample of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all records whose journey date is same then you need to remove group by option. Use following function

```
function slots($condition){
    $this->db->select('slot_id');
    $this->db->from('mn_date_slot');
    $this->db->where('journey_date',$condition);
    $this->db->order_by('slot_id','desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```